# Is "switched" always used as a verb?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, word-usage, syntactic-analysis

I was thinking that the word switched could be used as a noun and maybe an adjective too but I might just be making grammar mistakes. Switched in the dictionary only shows up as being a verb!

Here are the examples and comparison sentences I was using:
The shirts are brightly colored.
The shirts are wool.
The shirts are switched. (This sentence might be incorrect but it is the kind of sentence which I would use off the top of my head in everyday conversation. Switched seems like it's being used as a noun to me.)
The switched shirts are both wool. (Here is how I think that switched could be used as an adjective.)

Please let me know your thoughts on this and correct me if I errored in any way! I am trying to better understand my own language in order to better study another.

Comment: Sure you can say “The shorts are switched”—but what is it supposed to mean? Who switched them? And with what?

Comment: "Switched" is commonly used as an adjective.  Can't think of a case where it would be used as a noun.

Comment: That the dictionary only mentions it as a verb is because they probably don't want to include the use of the past particple as an adjective _for every verb in the dictionary_. Its just a very common way to use a verb's past participle.

Answer (score 2):

"Switched" is the past participle of the verb "to switch".  A past participle has several uses. Here are two: 1) It functions as an adjective in describing a noun: "The switched classrooms resulted in spotty attendance that first week".  2) It is used in forming the passive voice of the verb: "The children were accidentally switched at birth."  Virtually all English verbs have a past participle that can function in this way; however it cannot function as a noun.  For that, you can use the present participle: "I would never consider switching to another brand of laundry detergent."

Answer (score 1):

The participle of just about *any* verb can be used *attributively*. A short-cut way of saying that is saying it *acts* as an adjective.
Instead of mentioning for every verb that its participle may function like an adjective, most dictionaries do not include that.

A shirt can be washed, worn, bought, sold, switched, torn, lost, made, found, painted, burnt, etc. That does not mean you will find all those participles in a dictionary as an adjective — they are not.

Just about any word that can be used to act as an adjective can also be used as nouns, although that is not extremely common. That means I can do that with participles as well; I can certainly use *the punished* to refer to *the punished prisoner*, or *the conquered* to refer to *the conquered people*.

Again, if you look up *punish* or *conquer*, I doubt many dictionaries will feel the need to explicitly mention that you could use the past participle as a noun.

Referring to *the switched shirts* as *the switched* would be, I think, at best poetic.

In your sentence

> The shirts are switched.

*Switched* is certainly not a noun, by the way. It is again, an attributively used participle, in the same way you could use any adjective:

> The shirts are blue.

The only noun there is *shirts*, *are* is a *copula* linking the adjective *blue* to *the shirts*. Blue would only be a noun in a sentence like:

> The reds and the blues are switched.

Comment: I would quibble somewhat with the comment regarding the use of the past participle as a noun.  The fact is, virtually any word or phrase that's used as an adjective can perform this trick.  Examples: "Only the good die young."  "Dr. Richard Thorndyke arrives as new administrator of the Psycho-neurotic Institute for the Very, Very Nervous to discover some suspicious goings-on. " (from the plot of the movie "High Anxiety.")

Comment: @LarryTerrell: you're right, it follows from the attributive use and goes for actual adjectives as well, of course — I actually used that in the later example! — so I edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! I am extremely appreciative for your insight and feedback! Grammar is absolutely fascinating! I have never heard of an attributively used participle before now and plan to look further into it. Thanks for correcting my mistake when I thought that "switched" and "blue" we're acting as nouns. Now, I see that they are 100% adjectives. I am just used to adjectives coming before nouns instead of after. I understand this now completely thanks to your example sentence using "red and blues" as nouns. Once again, thank you!

Comment: Finally, thanks for making your explanation simple for me to understand since I have knowledge of only basic grammar. Most of the time, as a native speaker, I only play the language by ear. I do wish however, that dictionaries would provide extended information about every possible way in which a given word can be used. Is there a dictionary out there with extended insight into using words with variations in grammar?

Comment: @slyfin: there are things you can do with (almost) _every_ verb, like using the participles attributively. Most dictionary editors would not find it very useful to include that information with every verb, so they will only include exceptions; for instance when the attributively used participle has a different meaning from what one would expect. Think of it in the same way that dictionaries do not usually include all the declensions of a verb: if I look up the verb _walk_, the dictionary editor will assume I know how to form _he walks_ and _he walked_as they are completely regular.

Comment: @slyfin Sadly, such a dictionary would be far beyond what is realistic to compile. You could probably easily write at least an entire page on the usage of every form of every word in the language, and the dictionary would end up being millions and millions of pages. You’d need thousands of people working on it full-time to be able to make any leeway, and even then, individual words change their meaning and how their used all the time—they’d never be able to keep up! A much better place to start would be a _grammar_, which shows you all the principles. Then you, as a native speaker can apply…

Comment: …those principles to each word you encounter, and easily hear for yourself whether it works for each word. There are a few truly great grammars of the English language out there who explain how the language really _works_, all the cogs and wheels of it. The two most commonly recommended ones here are (annoyingly) both called [**CGEL**](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/CGEL), though the C stands for different things in their two titles.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Thank you for this! Which one of these 2 comprehensive texts covers the most basic theory? I am definitely interested in delving into the mechanics of grammar. Also, even though a comprehensive meaning dictionary + grammar dictionary together would take millions of pages to write wouldn't the internet make this possible? I'm thinking about huge community driven informational sites like Wikipedia! Maybe, somebody could one day implement such a comprehensive complete resource of words with thousands of examples of usage through the power of the Internet?

Comment: @slyfin I would suggest, if you’re not familiar with grammatical concepts at more than a rudimentary level, that you start out by getting lost in Wikipedia pages about various grammatical topics. They’re easy to find, easy to navigate, and (as you probably know) easy to spend hours in. They’re not always fully accurate, but they’re generally as good as any introductory book is likely to be. Once you feel like you understand how grammar ‘ticks’, either CGEL is very good. The 1985 one is more traditional, while the 2002 one is more of a radically new way of structuring things.